# Unable to locate package source : vcRuntimeDebug_amd64\cab1.cab visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I tried to install  Visual Studio 2012 . but it showing me "Unable to locate package source" I can select "Download from the internet" or "Provide a location to search for the packages" And this is path that comes up:

```
C:\Users\JA\Download\packages\vcRuntimeDebug_amd64\cab1.cab
```

(the 'packages' folder does not exists) When I select to download from the internet its showing up again after some time, I searched for "vcRuntimeDebug_amd64" folder but it doesn't contain "cab1.cab" file ;/

Note please, that i runned setup file as administrator and i disable firewall .

Comment: I am having this problem but with Windows Phone 8 SDK. I can't believe nobody has a solution for this!
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1d52b661-81d0-4c0c-a6ef-a7c58d3111f1/unable-to-locate-the-resource-in-windows-phone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but with Windows Phone 8 SDK. I tried several things (which are detailed below, in my previous answer), and the best option was to download the ISO, found in the *Install Instructions* section:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=35471

After finishing, it said it couldn't download that runtime, but at least the emulator is running fine. I guess you could manually download that runtime
afterwards if you have any problems. Here's the link:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=30679

---

**Previous attempts:**

I downloaded the *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4* to see if that way the installer skipped that step, but it didn't work.
Then I looked for **cab1.cab** in my disk and found it in several folders, being this one the one that worked:

```
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}v11.0.61030\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64
```

Of course that GUID will be different in your case, so you should look for a *vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64* folder.

Inside that folder was not only the cab1.cab but also a *vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi* file. When I told the installer to use that folder, it still didn't work. Then I chose "Browse" but when I opened that folder it didn't show any file because the installer was looking for *vcRuntimeMinimum_x64* (without the underscore). I typed "*.*" in the textbox so it showed all the files, I chose *vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi* and the installation continued. It took a while but it worked.

Later I had the same issue with **sdk_tools35res.cab**. I told the installer to use v3.11.50727\packages\sdk_tools35res\**sdk_tools35res.msi** and the process continued.

But in the end, I got three errors: Tools for .Net 3.5, MS VC++ runtime and .NET 4.5 SDK. So then I decided to download the ISO.

Comment: Well, there was another missing file, I used the same approach again, it seemed to work as well but in the end the installer showed both with errors. :( For the first problem, I found two files and used the latest one; I will try with the other one to see if I have luck...

Comment: Just edited my answer to reflect my latest findings.